# Next event with a new click, I'm missing something but what?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm new to jQuery and have a question I can't solve.

My question: I want to have multiple events with more clicks. At the moment a I have an image with a good and a false choice (if or else). But at the moment I click at the good choice, the text will change (=good), but also the tomato for the wrong choice appears on the screen.

For the next choice the tomato appears on screen also for the correct choice.... It's an image with five bottles (five clicks).

It must be something with bind / unbind or on/off, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me please?

```
<script>
var mousePos = {
x: 0,
y: 0
}
var number = "one";
function clickHandler() 
{

$(".apparatuur").click(function(e)
{
    mousePos.x = e.pageX;
    mousePos.y = e.pageY;
    {console.log(mousePos)
    if(number === "one")    
    if(mousePos.x > 33 && mousePos.x < 140 && mousePos.y > 40 && mousePos.y < 333)
            {console.log("click registered no.1")
            number = "two"
            clickThis()
            }
            else
            {console.log("click registered no.1")
             $(".tomaat").fadeIn()
             setTimeout(function()      {
                $(".tomaat").fadeOut()  }, 1000)
             number = "one"
            }
        }

    if(number === "two")
    {if(mousePos.x > 445 && mousePos.x < 600 && mousePos.y > 134 && mousePos.y < 344)
            {console.log("click registered no.2")
            number = "three"
            clickThis()
            }
            else
            {console.log("click registered no.2")
             $(".tomaat").fadeIn()
             setTimeout(function()      {
                $(".tomaat").fadeOut()  }, 1000)
             number = "two"
            }
        }

//three more clicks needed for numbers three, four and five.

})
}

function clickThis(){switch(number){
case "one": $(".clickthis").html("1. Click on the agent that makes sure the chemical sticks to the plant.").css("background-color", "white");
break;

case "two": $(".clickthis").html( "2. Click on the chemical that works against fungi." ).css ("background-color", "#ffff99");
break;

//case three, four and five...

case "done": $(".clickthis").html("You have done well.").css("background-color", "white");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
clickHandler()
clickThis()

})
</script>
```

Comment: Your code has many mistakes... primarily, you are missing semicolons on most of your code.

Comment: By putting semicolons the animation does not work anymore, it goes straight to case "done".

Comment: Thanks to a friend I've found a solution:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a friend I've found a solution

```
    if(number === "one")
    {   
        if(mousePos.x > 33 && mousePos.x < 140 && mousePos.y > 40 && mousePos.y < 333)
            {console.log("click registered no.1")

            //this timeout prevents the appearing of the tomato
            setTimeout(function() {
                number = "two"
                clickThis()
            }, 100)
            }
```